# openCV waitKey() can't get proper keyboard input

Tags: python, opencv

I followed a tutorial, and tried to make the program quit when I press `q`, but that doesn't work, it quits no matter which key I press, that's the code:

```
twi = cv2.imread('large.png')
cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('image', twi)
key = cv2.waitKey(0)
if key == ord('q'):
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And I've tried to add `&0xFF`:

```
key = cv2.waitKey(0)&0xFF
```

Still not working, what is wrong with it? Can I fix it?

=============Update============

I added `print(key)` to that, when pressing `q`, variable `key` is `113`, and `ord('q')` is `113` either, can't understand why it doesn't work...

=============Solved=============

(Seems that I forget how `if` works...)

Comment: "it quits no matter what key I pressed" show us the rest of the code, does it quit right after that shown lines? Then it is clear why it quits, because the code enters the if statement, sees "oh it isn't 'q' so just go on" and then it reaches the end of your code and quits.

Comment: @Micka Gosh I must be stupid at the moment... Now I understand... Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continuously calling `cv2.waitKey(0)` when it doesn't return the key value for the `q` key might work:

```
while cv2.waitKey(0) != ord('q'):
    pass
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```